# how the local variable organized in stack when function call?

Tags: c++

I run the follow code:

```
    void func()
    {
        int i;
        int array[10];

        cout << &i << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            cout << &array[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
```

the output is:

```
    0x28fe98
    0x28fe70
    0x28fe74
    0x28fe78
    0x28fe7c
    0x28fe80
    0x28fe84
    0x28fe88
    0x28fe8c
    0x28fe90
    0x28fe94
```

why the address of `i` is `0x28fe98`?
i think the address of `i` must be `&array[0] - 4`.
why the address of `i` is `&array[9] + 4` in fact?

Comment: The stack typically grows downward, with each variable going upward if it has multiple elements of some sort. Of course relying on that isn't good.

Comment: I am not really sure . But still Ill say, I will get to learn if I am wrong. Your array is expected to be allocated in continguos  manner and not all the variables declared in the code. The compiler will allocate memory for `i` where feasible

Comment: Actually, regardless of what it actually is, `operator<` must return `true` if the address of an element earlier in an array or structure (with them having the same access specifier) is compared with one later, so why not actually make that true in memory? That would be a good reason for the second part of my first comment. As for growing downward at all, I haven't looked into it enough to say, but it's probably either more efficient or traditional.

Comment: aside from stack going downward, there is no guarantee that the `array[9]` should start at `&i - 4` either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why the address of i is 0x28fe98?

It is located just after the end of your array

> i think the address of i must be &array[0] - 4.

Why should it be ?

> why the address of i is &array[9] + 4 in fact?

Because `i` is after your array :)

Typically elements are pushed on the stack and their adresses decrease while the heap limit increases but no code should rely on that except if you're on a low level (asm etc..)

Comment: i mean why the push sequence is not `i`,`array[0]`,...,`array[9]`.

Comment: @stamaimer because no standard says it has to be like this. And the most common implementations do the reverse. AFAIK it is just an easy way to seperate the heap from the stack and make them not collide until all the virtual memory of the program is used.